# Convert RSA public key, from XML to PEM (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, rsa, public-key, pem

How convert RSA public key, from XML to PEM (PHP)?

Comment: What do you mean by "XML", do you mean from a document using XML Signature: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we know

> .pem - (Privacy Enhanced Mail) Base64
>   encoded DER certificate, enclosed
>   between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
>   and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

[X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509)

> The SignatureValue element contains
>   the Base64 encoded signature result -
>   the signature generated with the
>   parameters specified in the
>   SignatureMethod element - of the
>   SignedInfo element after applying the
>   algorithm specified by the
>   CanonicalizationMethod.

[XML_Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature)

so we end up with

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile); // or simplexml_load_string

$pem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
$pem .= $xml->SignatureValue;
$pem .= "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

// save to file
```

if your xml-file isn't a XML_Signature

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile); // or simplexml_load_string
$pem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n";
$pem .= $xml->nodeWithWantedValue; // use base64_encode if needed
$pem .= "\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

Comment: Maybe it's the variable name that's misleading, but the signature value and the certificate (which you're putting in between the BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE) are two different things. In addition, the original question was about public keys, not certificate. In the XML Signature spec, the public key is split between modulus and exponent.

Comment: since we don't have any information about the mysterious xml... see it as an example. will modify the code to reflect that more clearly

Comment: Sure, but if it's the RSAKeyValue XML DSig format, you still need to reconstruct the ASN.1 structure and re-encode in into base-64 before putting it in between BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY. It's not just a matter of extracting the text from the XML. @mario's pointers would help then.

Comment: i always try to "think simple" if there is no clear definition. but of course your right.

Answer (score 10):

I'm assuming that by XML format, you mean [XML DSig RSAKeyValue](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-RSAKeyValue), and that by PEM format you mean what OpenSSL exports in between `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`.

You need first to extract the modulus and public exponent from the XML.

```
   <RSAKeyValue>
     <Modulus>xA7SEU+e0yQH5rm9kbCDN9o3aPIo7HbP7tX6WOocLZAtNfyxSZDU16ksL6W
      jubafOqNEpcwR3RdFsT7bCqnXPBe5ELh5u4VEy19MzxkXRgrMvavzyBpVRgBUwUlV
      5foK5hhmbktQhyNdy/6LpQRhDUDsTvK+g9Ucj47es9AQJ3U=
     </Modulus>
     <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
   </RSAKeyValue>
```

You can easily convert these into a bit string using [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Once this is done, you need to build the [ASN.1](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) public key structure somehow.

What OpenSSL exports between BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY is an [X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.509-200508-I/en).

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
   algorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
   subjectPublicKey BIT STRING }
```

The `subjectPublicKey` is made of a sequnce is described in the [PKCS#1 spec](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125):

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
   modulus INTEGER,
   publicExponent INTEGER
}
```

The `algorithm` (an `AlgorithmIdentifier`) is also described in the PKCS#1 spec (see section A.1):

```
rsaEncryption
OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { pkcs-1 1 }
```

This structure needs to be serialized in DER form, then base64-encoded and then placed between the BEGIN/END delimiters.

I don't know of any PHP library to do the ASN.1/DER encoding unfortunately (the rest is relatively easy, but dealing with ASN.1 tends to be tedious).

The [PHP/PEAR Crypt_RSA module](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_RSA/docs/latest/li_Crypt_RSA.html) can construct RSA public keys from modulus and exponent, but its `toString()` method uses a custom format (just the base64-encoding of the result of PHP `serialize` on the array structure, which has nothing to do with the ASN.1/DER encoding).

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard for storing RSA public keys in XML.  So the manner of conversion will depend on the XML you have.

Comment: There is a W3C recommendation that specifies this: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-RSAKeyValue

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here is a working example of creating the PEM from modulus in python. You could call it in a subprocess from PHP if necessary.

The meat of the solution is:

```
def big_endian(n):
    s = '%x' % n
    if len(s) & 1:
        s = '0' + s
    return s.decode('hex')

from M2Crypto import RSA

e = E_PREFIX + big_endian(public_exponent)
n = N_PREFIX + big_endian(modulus)

new = RSA.new_pub_key((e,n))
new.save_key('foo.pub')
```

Where `E_PREFIX` and `N_PREFIX` are constants that (as far as I can tell) depend on the exponent and key length. Here is a quick table I have constructed:

```
E_PREFIX = '\x00\x00\x00\x01' # 0x3 (3)
E_PREFIX = '\x00\x00\x00\x03' # 0x10001 (65537)

N_PREFIX = '\x00\x00\x00!\x00' # 256-bit
N_PREFIX = '\x00\x00\x00A\x00' # 512-bit (default)
N_PREFIX = '\x00\x00\x00\x81\x00' # 1024-bit
N_PREFIX = '\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00' # 2048-bit
N_PREFIX = '\x00\x00\x02\x01\x00' # 4096-bit
```

If someone knows a more general way to compute the prefixes, do tell.