# What part of the key object do I pass into `openssl_verify` to verify a Google signed JWT?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, google-oauth, jwt

I'm trying to implement a federated login system with Google and OpenID Connect, and I'm stuck verifying and parsing the JWT id token I get back from Google. I'm following [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#validatinganidtoken) here.

Taking the advise of the docs, I'm trying to use an existing JWT library. The most popular PHP version on GitHub seems to be [PHP_JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt). The problem appears to be in the format of the JWK keys.

Google's docs, linked above, say to get the keys from the `jwks_uri` endpoint as shown in their discovery doc. That endpoint returns the following:

```
{
 "keys": [
  {
   "kty": "RSA",
   "alg": "RS256",
   "use": "sig",
   "kid": "1771931eb0eb64eb97733e857685be153e079bb9",
   "n": "AMNFQMNJw/EVwrYsyPTnEHWkaPinPb4ngc/SqD701aisFhbU9/wWoKADeFtwfBcWl1qjzIqhPorQElB+2mtiqUh3Qtaazt1x5wA9XnJDe6kjtMGm9nNLMilSVNBilAE8GIdbciMycISfOfL0WRaJrqpNxewNEVZjuYiGzOWahiDP",
   "e": "AQAB"
  },
  {
   "kty": "RSA",
   "alg": "RS256",
   "use": "sig",
   "kid": "7b3bc600209875d3c42ae277a0d018d1d21986ec",
   "n": "AN2UvG5+hNEMIPIbnpPm+JQi6LFWXBPzg3Ltb3xkVmSTjVaCFWppw/ZYRBgpToGKZP9XJstlOE88SDUFSMZIkIqtLpnUqmZax2Zc2gjEB9PhmHSH3/tTmtZ1U0X6V+crqitZ2uc3NV78vCn9/s+WuPwk/gfKBG8Cirb0fgLmsPd9",
   "e": "AQAB"
  }
 ]
}
```

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/Authentication/JWT.php#L57) for the JWT class's `decode` and `verify` methods, it seems like the `$keys` parameter can be an array, but they expect the array keys to be the `kid` and the array values to be: `@param string|resource $key for HS*, a string key works. for RS*, must be a resource of an openssl public key`. It's simple enough to pull out the `kid` properties and use them as array keys, but what should be used as the array values?

From Google's JWKs document, it looks like we're using `RS*`, but I have no idea what part of the key object is the `resource of an openssl public key`. I've tried using the entire stdClass object and just the `n` string, but both fail at the [`openssl_verify`](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/Authentication/JWT.php#L152) step. That function emits a notice saying: "Warning: openssl_verify(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a public key".

So, obviously, I'm passing in the wrong key, but what is the right key?

[Google's library](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-php) for this seems to use a [different endpoint](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-php/blob/89a459fc4f995b4b2a4c0e0a8d52549d5e4b9035/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php#L45) to get the keys. That endpoint seems to return an array of certs. Do I need to use something like that instead? If so, why would the docs tell you to use the `jwks_uri` endpoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both endpoints contain the same informations but in different format.

The `jwks_uri` endpoint give you the **modulus** and **exponent** value of the RSA public key. You can use these two values to generate the PEM file you get at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new to cryptography, so I did not have the vocabulary I needed. Would you recommend I switch endpoints or use a different JWT library that can handle the format provided at the `jwks_uri` endpoint?

Comment: Well, I'm not at all a php expert so i cannot make a recommendation on the JWT library you should use. However I found these two topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973086/how-to-generate-a-der-pem-certificate-from-public-exponent-and-modulus-of-rsa and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568012/convert-rsa-public-key-from-xml-to-pem-php. They can help you if you still want to use the `jwks_uri` endpoint and build a PEM using the **modulus** and **exponent** values.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I found a nice [PHP JWT library](https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/phpjwx/overview) that seems to support the modulus and exponent key format, so I think changing to that will be the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 10):

For the people trying to do this in the future I'd like to provide a full answer;

The `n` and `e` parts in the `jwks_uri` JSON keys give the modulus and the exponent, which can be used to retrieve the public key (which is all that is required to verify the signature). How this is done in pure PHP is detailed in this post:

[openssl: how can i get public key from modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993838/openssl-how-can-i-get-public-key-from-modulus)

**However**, you should be aware that the JSON document provided at Google's `jwks_uri` uses URL safe base64 encoding (i.e. normal base64 with the + and / characters replaced). Failing to take this into account might still give you an invalid certificate. Since you mention using `php-jwt`, working code to get the public key from the modulus and the exponent using [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) is:

```
$modulus = 'someencodedmodulusvalue';
$exponent = 'someencodedexponentvalue'; 
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

$modulus = new Math_BigInteger(JWT::urlsafeB64Decode($modulus), 256);
$exponent = new Math_BigInteger(JWT::urlsafeB64Decode($exponent), 256);

$rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent));
$rsa->setPublicKey();
$pubKey = $rsa->getPublicKey();
```